# CompletableFuture single task that continues with many parallel tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, completable-future

I have the following code:

```
return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    return foo; // some custom object
})
.thenAccept(foo -> {
     // ??? need to spawn N async parallel jobs that works on 'foo'
});
```

In english: the first task creates the `foo` object asynchronously; and then I need to run N parallel processes on it.

Is there a better way to do this then:

```
...
CompletableFuture[] parallel = new CompletableFuture[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    parallel[i] = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        work(foo);
    });
}
CompletableFuture.allOf(parallel).join();
...
```

I don't like this as one thread gets locked while waiting N jobs to finish.

Comment: Why do you have that line `CompletableFuture.allOf(parallel).join();` when you don’t want to wait for the completion? Nobody requires you to wait…

Comment: i was blind at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain as many independent jobs as you like on a particular prerequisite job, e.g.

```
CompletableFuture<Foo> base=CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new Foo());
Collections.nCopies(N, base).forEach(f -> f.thenAcceptAsync(foo -> work(foo)));
```

will spawn `N` parallel jobs, invoking `work(foo)` concurrently, after the completion of the initial job which provides the `Foo` instance.

But keep in mind, that the underlying framework will consider the number of available CPU cores to size the thread pool actually executing the parallel jobs, so if `N > #cores`, some of these jobs may run one after another.

If the work is I/O bound, thus, you want to have a higher number of parallel threads, you have to specify your own executor.

---

The `nCopies`/`forEach` is not necessary, a `for` loop would do as well, but it provides a hint of how to handle subsequent jobs, that depend on the completion of all these parallel jobs:

```
CompletableFuture<Foo> base=CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new Foo());
CompletableFuture<Void> all = CompletableFuture.allOf(
    Collections.nCopies(N, base).stream()
        .map(f -> f.thenAcceptAsync(foo -> work(foo)))
        .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new));
```

Now you can use `all` to check for the completion of all jobs or chain additional actions.

Comment: *"If the work is I/O bound, thus, you want to have a higher number of parallel threads"* -- why is this?  Perhaps you're missing **synchronous** I/O bound, or better yet, *"If the work is **blocking**"*.

Comment: @acelent: [I/O bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound) is a general term used for all kinds of potentially blocking tasks, opposed to *CPU bound* tasks. The default executor used by `CompletableFuture` is configured suitable for CPU bound tasks, that’s all needed to know…

Comment: *"[I/O bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound) is a general term used for all kinds of potentially blocking tasks, opposed to CPU bound tasks."* -- Then, just allow me to disagree.  I've bridged `CompletableFuture` over `AsynchronousSocketChannel`'s methods that take a `CompletionHandler`, and it definitely didn't need more thread-pool threads than cores, since it didn't block.  However, using any kind of blocking code, be it I/O, waiting or sleeping, will probably require more thread-pool threads to have as many runnable threads as cores.  There's no I/O in waiting or sleeping.

Comment: @acelent: don’t try to redefine well-established terms. “I/O bound” uses “I/O” in the sense of everything not handled by the CPU itself. If you are pushing requests to an uncontended queue, it’s not I/O bound, even if the consumer of the queue is called `AsynchronousSocketChannel`. Well, and if you let the `CompletionHandler` of the `AsynchronousSocketChannel` complete the `CompletableFuture` you *are* effectively using a different executor—that of the `AsynchronousSocketChannel`.

Comment: *"don’t try to redefine well-established terms."* -- Whatever.  *"Well, and if you let the `CompletionHandler` of the `AsynchronousSocketChannel` complete the `CompletableFuture` you are effectively using a different executor—that of the `AsynchronousSocketChannel`."* -- The consumer either accepts this or uses the `*Async` methods.  But this is going offtopic, I just brought this as an example of actual "I/O", e.g. yielding/sleeping or waiting on a lock, mutex, semaphore, etc. is not "I/O".  I mean, not even that wikipedia article supports your definition.  Let's just agree to disagree.

Comment: @acelent: the term dates back to the early days of Unix, if not even earlier. There is simply a distinction between *CPU bound* processes and *I/O bound* processes and nothing else. You only need to read the first two sentences of the Wikipedia article to get that message. For a scheduler, that distinction is simple to implement, just based on how much actual CPU time a process consumes. I see that you obviously understand the topic, but just don’t like the wording, but I will stay with the established-for-decades wording instead of introducing unnecessary complications.

Answer (score 0):

Since `CompletableFuture.allOf` already returns another `CompletableFuture<Void>`a you can just do another `.thenAccept` on it and extract the returned values from the CFs in `parallel` in the callback, that way you avoid calling `join`

Comment: Or I can make array outside and then create parallel tasks with `thenAcceptAsync` in a loop.